# как удалить строку содержащую слово

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть большой csv файл, в нём нужно удалить все строки, содержащие определённые слова или символы. Например, если в строке есть символ `%`, то нужно удалить всю строку.

Comment: Простая проверка с помощью оператора `in` может Вам помочь. Для более сложных вариантов регулярные выражения в помощь. Хотя если у вас есть проблема, и Вы собираетесь решать её с использованием регулярных выражений, то у вас две проблемы :D

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('your.csv', 'r') as f:
    '\n'.join([','.join([j for j in i.split(',') if '%' not in j]) for i in f.read().split('\n')])
```